# JavaScript Photo Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Am trying to build a photo gallery with javascript ony (no jQuery). Such that i hover one image and the image and alt text shows in an empty div.

```js
var bgImages_1 = 'url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg)';
        var bgImages_2 = 'url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG)';
        var bgImages_3 = 'url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg)';
        
        backImages = bgImages_1 && bgImages_2 && bgImages_3;
        
        
        var undoAlt = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
        var undoText = "";
        
        
  function upDate(previewPic){
            
   document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
            document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = bgImages_1;
        }
  function unDo(undotext){
   document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = undoAlt;
            document.getElementById('image').style.background = undoText;
  }
```

```css
body{
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
#image{
    line-height:650px;
  width: 575px;
    height: 650px;
  border:5px solid black;
  margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #8e68ff;
    background-image: url('');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    font-size: 150%;
}
.preview{
  width:10%;
  margin-left:17%;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
img{
  width:95%;
}
```

```html
<div id = "image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
 </div>
 
 <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
 
 <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
 
 <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
```

I have tried different methods but succeeded in only the alt text

Comment: `document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = bgImages_1;` you're always using the first image with this, instead you should check which image is hovered and display that one.

Comment: How can that be done. Because i cant seem to get that right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the backgroundImage to previewPic.src

If you run the source code below, you can see that it works well.

```js
var bgImages_1 = 'url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg)';
        var bgImages_2 = 'url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG)';
        var bgImages_3 = 'url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg)';
        
        backImages = bgImages_1 && bgImages_2 && bgImages_3;
        
        
        var undoAlt = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
        var undoText = "";
        
        
  function upDate(previewPic){
            
   document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+previewPic.src+')';
        }
  function unDo(undotext){
   document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = undoAlt;
            document.getElementById('image').style.background = undoText;
  }
```

```css
body{
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
#image{
    line-height:650px;
  width: 575px;
    height: 650px;
  border:5px solid black;
  margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #8e68ff;
    background-image: url('');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    font-size: 150%;
}
.preview{
  width:10%;
  margin-left:17%;
    border: 10px solid black;
}
img{
  width:95%;
}
```

```html
<div id = "image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
 </div>
 
 <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
 
 <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
 
 <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
```

Comment: in this example you don't need the `var bgImages_*`

Comment: Bakyuns thanks alot works perfectly. Now i understand why i didn't get it right. Kevin realized that, wrote it in the process of trying to figure it out.